# exchange two words using sed

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sed

I am trying to exchange two words in a line but it doesn't work.
For example:
"Today is my first day of university" should be "my is Today first day of university"

This is what I tried:

```
sed 's/\([a-zA-z0-9]\)\([a-zA-z0-9]\)\([a-zA-z0-9]\)/\3\2\1/' filename.txt
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @warl0ck, I'm not sure we should add backslashes into sed command or fix it any other way directly in the question.

Comment: Why do people keep changing the Q here? The OP has erroneous pattern as @rush points out in answer. This makes answer look out of place - and is no help for poster.

Comment: Aha. The back-slashes was there, but disappear when not as code block. Thanks @rush for [Q on this](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1202/fixing-the-code-directly-in-the-question). Original post [plain text](http://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/d7451fa4-e0fb-497e-b642-ea20b7dca422/view-source).

Answer (score 9):

Try this one:

```
sed -r 's/([a-zA-Z0-9]+) ([a-zA-Z0-9]+) ([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/\3 \2 \1/'
```

Your problem is that you're tryng to use extended regex without `-r` option or escape symbol in sed command.

Also the regex isn't fully correct.

You're specifying incorrect range: there is no `A-z` range, there is `A-Z`.

Also you forgot spaces and you didn't specify that words are multicharacter.