# Switch two arbitrary length strings separated by a symbol

Tags: sed

I'm trying to split a filename consisting of arbitrary number of space-separated words into two separate strings by searching for the first occurrence of a symbol '-', and then switch the order of those strings. For e.g if the filename is originally

> word1 word 2 ... word9 - wordA wordB ... wordZ

then the desired output is

> wordA wordB ... wordZ - word1 word2 ... word9

Note that there can be more than 1 word on both sides of the '-'. My sed code is

```
sed -r 's/([a-zA-Z0-9]+) \- ([a-zA-Z0-9])*/\2 \- \1/'
```

My question is how to specify arbitrary number of words before and after the '-' in sed. I am aware that sed only supports up to 9 patterns.

I've read [a past question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70600/exchange-two-words-using-sed) but the question is about switching a known fixed number of words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo 'word1 word 2 ... word9 - wordA wordB ... wordZ' | sed 's/\(.*\) - \(.*\)/\2 - \1/'
```

Output:

```
wordA wordB ... wordZ - word1 word 2 ... word9
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much. Now I need to learn what /(.*\) means from sed documentation.