# Swap two strings separated by a symbol in multiple filenames of a directory

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I want to change a string like `author - name` in some books' filenames to `name - author`. I'm trying

```
ls * | sed -r 's/(.+) - (.+).pdf/mv \2 - \1.pdf/' | sh
```

Maybe its a mix of 
[Switch two arbitrary length strings separated by a symbol](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/258700/switch-two-arbitrary-length-strings-separated-by-a-symbol)
and [Rename multiple files with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17137566/rename-multiple-files-with-sed)

This doesn't work

```
for file in *; do mv "$file" "$(echo "$file" | sed -r 's/(.+) - (.+).pdf/\2 - \1.pdf/')"
```

Neither does

```
rename 's/\([.]+\) - \([.]+\)\.pdf/\2 - \1\.pdf/' *
```

This works

```
rename 's/(.+) - (.+).pdf/\2 - \1.pdf/' *
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Try this

```
% ls -1                                                                                                       
001-foobar.pdf
002-foobar.pdf
003-foobar.pdf
```

#### Code

```
% rename -n 's/([^-]+)-([^\.]+)\.pdf/$2-$1.pdf/' *.pdf                                                          
001-foobar.pdf -> foobar-001.pdf
002-foobar.pdf -> foobar-002.pdf
003-foobar.pdf -> foobar-003.pdf
```

#### Note

(remove -n switch when your tests are OK)

[image: warning]
 **There are other tools with the same name which may or may not be able to do this, so be careful.**

If you run the following command (`GNU`)

```
$ file "$(readlink -f "$(type -p rename)")"
```

and you have a result like

```
.../rename: Perl script, ASCII text executable
```

and not containing:

```
ELF
```

then this seems to be the right tool =)

If not, to make it the default (usually already the case) on `Debian` and derivative like `Ubuntu` :

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --set rename /path/to/rename
```

(replace `/path/to/rename` to the path of your `perl's rename` command.

---

If you don't have this command, search your package manager to install it or [do it manually](https://metacpan.org/module/RMBARKER/File-Rename-0.20/rename.PL)

---

Last but not least, this tool was originally written by Larry Wall, the Perl's dad.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the filenames follow the pattern `author - name.pdf` and that both `author` and `name` may contain any valid character apart from `-` surrounded by spaces.

```
find . -type f -name '* - *.pdf' \
    -execdir sh -c 'b=${1% - *}; e=${1#* - }; mv "$1" "${e%.pdf} - $b.pdf"' sh {} \;
```

This finds all regular files in the current directory that have names matching the pattern `* - *.pdf`.

For each such file, a subshell is executed.  The subshell does the following:

```
b=${1% - *}  # pick out the start of the filename
e=${1#* - }  # pick out the end of the filename

# Combine $b and $e into a new filename while removing ".pdf" from
# the end of the original filename and adding it to the end of
# the new filename instead.
mv "$1" "${e%.pdf} - $b.pdf"
```

Testing it:

```
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel  0 Aug 30 11:31 arr! - Boaty McBoatface.pdf
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel  0 Aug 30 11:30 hello world - bingo-night!.pdf

$ find . -type f -name '* - *.pdf' -execdir sh -c 'b=${1% - *}; e=${1#* - }; mv "$1" "${e%.pdf} - $b.pdf"' sh {} \;

$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel  0 Aug 30 11:31 Boaty McBoatface - arr!.pdf
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel  0 Aug 30 11:30 bingo-night! - hello world.pdf
```

Running it again would swap the names back to their originals.