# Remane filename by switching what is before and after an underscore

Tags: bash, sed, grep, rename, mv

I would like to rename a number of files that have the following formatting:

```
ABCD_20181102.jpg
DEDE_2_20181030.jpg
```

i.e usually 4 random letters, followed by an underscore and a date (year, month, day). Or 4 random letters followed by an underscore, a random number, an underscore and then a date.

I would like to rename these files to date, (random number if needed), and then random letters, like the following:

```
20181102_ABCD.jpg
20181030_2_DEDE.jpg
```

Comment: I am a brainlet, and whenever i have to do something similar, i usually find the answer (online), can't seem to find how to switch strings that are before/after underscores  ...

Comment: Dupe (with no upvoted answers): https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/314010/swap-two-strings-separated-by-a-symbol-in-multiple-filenames-of-a-directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Parameter expansion to extract parts of the strings. `#` removes from the left, `%` removes from the right, doubling the symbol removes the longest possible match.

```
#! /bin/bash
for f in ABCD_20181102.jpg DEDE_2_20181030.jpg ; do
    suffix=${f#*.}
    before_underscore=${f%%_*}
    after_underscore=${f#*_}
    after_underscore=${after_underscore%.$suffix}
    if [[ $after_underscore = *_* ]] ; then
        before2=${after_underscore%_*}
        after2=${after_underscore#*_}
        after_underscore="$after2"_"$before2"
    fi
    echo mv "$f" "$after_underscore"_"$before_underscore.$suffix"
done
```

Just remove the `echo` before `mv` once you have checked the script does what you need.

Comment: @badaboum: "Thanks" on StackExchange = upvote/accept.

Comment: sry, forgot to accept ... i don't have enough reputation to upvote :-(

Answer (score 0):

If you have Larry Wall's rename, then

`rename -n -e 's/.*_.*/$2_$1/' «file list»`

Remove `-n` to enable, if output shows that it will do it correctly. (The above only tells you what it would do, but will not do it.)

Answer (score 0):

With `mmv`:

```
$ mmv -n '*_*.jpg' '#2_#1.jpg'
ABCD_20181102.jpg -> 20181102_ABCD.jpg
DEDE_2_20181030.jpg -> 2_20181030_DEDE.jpg
```

(remove the `-n` once you are sure it's doing the right thing).